# Why doesn't this RegEx work with `git grep`?

Tags: regex, git, character-encoding

The input is Unicode texts.

### input

```
あいうえお
```

### command

Execution environment is macOS.

```
git grep '[い]' # -> matched
grep 'あ[い]う' # -> matched

git grep 'あ[い]う' # -> not matched
```

Why doesn't the RegEx work in `git grep` when normal `grep` is works?

### environment

OS: macOS
Locale: ja_JP.UTF-8

Input file encoding is 'UTF-8'.

Comment: I'm guessing `grep` does Unicode normalization and `git` doesn't. Can you show the actual bytes in your command line and in the file you hope should match? Perhaps see also the  [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)

Comment: (Provided this even is Unicode in the first place - probably [edit] your question to clarify this.)

Comment: sorry, I can’t understand what you’re saying. My English is not good enough yet.
What kind of editing is needed?

Comment: Tell us the encoding you are using. Is this Unicode (Mac/Linux) or some Windows code page? What's the output of `locale` or Windows `chcp`?

Answer (score 4):

All of my experiments show that `git grep` uses ASCII-8BIT encoding:

```
git grep 'あ[い][い][い]う'
# matches (because \xE3, \x81 and \x84 match [\xe3\x81\x84])
git grep 'あ[か]'
# matches (because \xE3, the first byte of い, matches [\xe3\x81\x8b])
```

The last one even explicitly shows you matched bytes.

Since character class (`[...]`) is the only construct in RegExp that considers individual characters and not strings, and since all character class regexps can trivially be rewritten into alternation regexps, here's a workaround: if regexp were `'上[げが]る'`, you can write

```
git grep '上\(げ\|が\)る'  # (alternation instead of character class)
git grep -E '上(げ|が)る'  # (prettier with extended regexp syntax)
```

Comment: Thank you for a very clear explanation!

I knew it would be replaced.
I didn't use it because I really wanted to match `あ[(（]い[)）]う`.

I didn't want to use escape, so I used "character class".
However, 'character class' does not work, so use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine for me:

```py
$ echo 'あいうえお' > afile
$ git add afile
$ grep 'あ[い]う' afile
あいうえお
$ git grep 'あ[い]う'
afile:あいうえお
```

Maybe you've configured `patternType` away from the default somehow?

> #### grep.patternType
>
> Set the default matching behavior. Using a value of basic, extended, fixed, or perl will enable the --basic-regexp, --extended-regexp, --fixed-strings, or --perl-regexp option accordingly, while the value default will return to the default matching behavior.

Try invoking `git grep -G` to force basic patterns and see what happens. Or `git config --get grep.patternType` to see if it's been set to somethig odd.

Also be aware that git grep only looks in "the tracked files in the work tree, blobs registered in the index file, or blobs in given tree objects". So if you add the string to a file but don't add the file to the index, there will be no match.

Likewise if the string is in an old commit, which is very much unlike `hg grep` (which greps through the history by default)

Comment: I can confirm that on both my Linux and my Mac your sequence does not work, not as you wrote it, not with `-G`, not with `-E`. However, `git grep -P 'あ[い]う'` does (on Mac).

Comment: Might have something to do with the environment (locale / encoding) then.

Comment: I don't know. Both systems I tried on are `en_US.UTF-8`. But definitely something wonky regarding Unicode — likely `git grep` assuming ASCII-8BIT, where `[い]` is any of the two bytes; but in `あ[い]う` we explicitly want a single character between あ and う, so fail. Note that `git grep 'あ[い]*う'` works (likely as both the bytes are matched as one of the required two bytes).

Comment: Sorry, three bytes, not two: 0xE3 0x81 0x84

Comment: Doesn't explain why it works fine on my system though, or why `git grep` would diverge from the normal `grep`.

Comment: No, it does not. I'm merely reporting results of my experiments, which apparently agree with OP's environment.

Comment: @Amadan but does a bare grep behave "as expected" on your system, or does it misbehave like git grep?

Comment: `grep` works as expected, just as OP reports. `grep 'あ[い]う' afile` finds it, `LC_ALL=ISO-8859-1 grep 'あ[い]う' afile` does not. It seems `git grep` is ignoring the locale (which is I guess kind of sensible, since your source files might not be written in a language of your system). Again, no idea why it works in your environment (which, BTW, you did not specify :P )